# I have a null pointer exceception when I try to open my Facebook I am working with a Samsung galaxy with Android

Tags: android, facebook

when I try to logon to Facebook  there is the following message : null pointer exception atteint to invoke virtual method'.com.Facebook omnistore collection name$ Builder.

I know absolutely  nothing on computers, so if you have an answer for me please make it as simple as possible. 
Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming at all

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to your phone issues. I have been observing it happening in a lot of phones. It's their bug. Most probably they have forgotten to handle such errors cases gracefully so that the layman's doesn't need to bother about the weirdo Null Pointer Exception. 
Is your doubt clear now?

Comment: So it will go  like it came ?

Comment: Could be an update of its a client side bug or it will go without updating  if it's a server side bug.